# Finding the Equation of a Line where x is datetime

Tags: linear-algebra

**My Task:**
I want to calculate the angle of two lines where I have only two points of each line. each one before and after the two lines cross.

**What I found/tried:**
Now with my old school knowlage I found this formular and it seems plausible

```
tan=((m1-m2)/(1-m1*m2))
```

However I have problems getting the equation of each of the lines, since my x is a datetime format and the y is a double.

Now I found the procedure with integer values
1. find slope of each line

```
slope = m = ( y2 - y1 ) / ( x2 - x1 )
```

2.find the equation of the line

```
equation= y - y1 = m ( x - x1 )
```

I calculated this through and it seems to work.

**Question:**
How do I find the equation when my Y values are datetime formats?

**Example:**
X Value for both lines:
x1 = 2017.12.12 14:51-----x2 = 2017.12.12 14:52

y of Line1:
L1y1 = 13148,148----------L1y2 = 13145,069

y of Line2:
L2y1 = 13145,428----------L2y2 = 13146,313

I would appriciate if someone could explain to me how to solve this or where I might find the answer.
thanks

Comment: Your question is about programming specifics and doesn’t really have much to do with linear algebra. Convert the datetimes to seconds since epoch.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: As $x$s and $y$s have different dimensions, in the original formulation there’s no sense to talk about angle between lines. First a choice of a unit distance between dates should be done, and hopelessly there is no canonical one.

Comment: "datetime formats" is not a mathematical issue. It's a language implementation issue, If you don't know how to convert datetime formats into a numeric time-since-epoch, ask that on Stack Overflow, not Math Exchange. However, expect to be told RTM (Read The Manual) there (often with an additional letter added to the abbreviation). You can find this information for your language on-line fairly easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with *datetime formats* can be solved using the Julian day numbers.

To convert from current date to Julian day number, just have a look [here](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/%7Ecs1063/projects/Spring2011/Project1/jdn-explanation.html) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Converting_Gregorian_calendar_date_to_Julian_Day_Number) . The formula is quite simple.

For sure, this will give you large numbers but you could shift them in order to have "human sized" values.

Today, december 19, 2017 at 5:36:34 am, the corresponding Julian date is exactly $2458106.73373$.